# Altering the 'forgot password' behavior?

Tags: login, users, password, authentication

Under our login form, I have a 'forgot password' link which goes to the native EE page for this: /members/forgot_password. When the link is clicked:

- EE sends an email to the user.
- User clicks on link.
- EE resets password to something random.
- EE emails new password to user.

I'd like the change this sequence so the user can create a new password. How would I do this?

Thx.

Comment: @alex-kendrick So there's no way to alter EE's behavior in this area without an add-on? Thanks.

Comment: Correct. This was one of our main concerns when we built FreeMember, as the native EE process is ridiculous to say the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two add-ons which will allow the password reset to work as you described, with the user entering their own password:

[**FreeMember**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember)
See the [reset_password tag](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/wiki/Reset-Password-Tag)

> The Reset Password tag allows users to change their password directly,
>   after they click the link in their email.

OR

[**Securit:ee**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/securitee)
See the [forgot_password tag](http://www.mithra62.com/docs/detail/securitee-template-tags/forgot-password)

> Instead of resetting a password Securit:ee sends a confirmation code,
>   that auto expires, and allows users to set their own passwords